# Deploy/test without packaging

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

Is there some way to get the android SDK build process to do partial updates on the actual device? Whenever I make a change it has to rebuild the apk file and deploy it, which seems wasteful, and is slow (especially with the dex defect).

The copying to the device isn't an issue here, it is fast enough. So the emulator doesn't appear to solve my problem. Is there perhaps a way to test the code without producing the APK file for the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is Test Driven Development (TDD).  This article will start you off right :

http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/

Comment: I've looked at that, and I'll definitely be using such a system, but I'm looking for a way to visually/manually test the interface itself. That is, while I'm experimenting with APIs and the devices I'm not at the point where I need test automation. I want to test the visuals and application manually at this point.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some way to get the android SDK build process to do partial updates on the actual device?

Not presently. It's something they are considering for a future overhaul of the build system, though I think there are other capabilities that are considered to be higher priority..

> Is there perhaps a way to test the code without producing the APK file for the emulator?

Not with standard Java-based Android development. Any sort of compiled environment pretty much needs the code to be compiled in order for it to be run.

Comment: I understand it needs to be compiled, but the APK goes way beyond that by packaging. I guess I'll have to wait until the toolchain is improved.